# Is my checkNumber() function secure?

Tags: xss, javascript

```
function checkNumber(number) {
        event = document.all ? window.event : number;
        key = document.all ? event.keyCode : event.which;
        window.event.keyCode
        if(key<48||key>57) {
            if(document.all) { event.returnValue = false; } else { event.preventDefault(); }
        }
    }
```

This is my function for preventing users to enter anything but numbers. But still not sure if it is secure since users may interact with it via a textbox. Thank you.
Textbox code:

```
<input name="TCashpoint" type="text" required="required" class="LBInput" placeholder="Enter only an integer." onkeypress="checkNumber(number)" maxlength="9">
```

PS: This is the client side code.

Comment: Is this serverside or just client side? If it is client side please be aware that the end user can alter the input before sending it to the server.

Comment: Oh forgot that js serverside is a thing... This is clientside and function is called whenever text box changes.

Comment: consider copy-paste into the textbox.

Comment: Data sent to server should be validated there. Client side validation is for UI/UX purpose only. Also why not use regex for validation ?

Comment: Well, to be honest, I didn't know how to use regex when I wrote this script and am too lazy to change since it still checks on the server side. I was just curious about can this kind of code cause a vulnerability.

Answer (score 4):

All client side code insecure by design. Unfortunately no matter how well you code your function, it can be easily bypassed by the end user. If this data is going to be passed to a server please validate it at the server end as well.

Client side validation is purely for '*usability*' and not security (i.e. let the client know that they have added an incorrect answer, genuine users will change their answer to conform, malicious users will edit the code or use a proxy to send off malicious text). For security you must check it on the server side.

Comment: I already check it on the server but I thought also checking here might be useful. But is it secure to let this code stay in my client? Or is it a bad idea? What harm can malicious person do?

Comment: It should be fine, a malicious person should not be able to harm your server with this function. Although I think you will find ```key<48||key>57``` should be ```key<=48||key>=57```

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues with your code:

1. The code is unclear and does not follow typical "norms".  In particular, you pass in `number`, but with the way you call it - `onkeypress="checkNumber(number)"` - `number` will always be undefined.  Instead you use an unnecessary check on `document.all` to pull the event out of the window object. Confusing code is harder to maintain, and hard-to-maintain code is code where it is easy to accidentally introduce security vulnerabilities later.
2. You are using inline listeners.  While not the end of the world, this will make it impossible for you to generate a strict CSP, which is a tricky but effective tool for mitigating the risk of XSS vulnerabilities.  Like point #1 above, inline listeners are a way of managing events that is harder to maintain, increasing the risk of security vulnerabilities.  While this isn't an immediate concern, in the long run you'll do yourself a favor if you learn how to manage events by attaching listeners from within javascript instead of attaching listeners inline (most front-end frameworks will make this very easy for you).

Also, [HTML5 has plenty of ways to do this without any code at all.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808590/html5-number-input-type-that-takes-only-integers)  Use one of those methods and save yourself a lot of trouble. Especially since `document.all` is deprecated. Once it disappears this code will break.